# Create multiple folders or folder structure in one go in Aptana?

Tags: html, css, aptana

I know only how to create one folder at a time in my Aptana web project. Can I create multipl folders at a time ? That is, create my project structure in one go ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this task by creating a

> batch file or using ant files

For an example crate a skeleton of the folder structure in C:/skeleton and you can copy this structure to aptana's work space y running your batch/ant file

For batch file creation, refer the following link, 
    [batch file](http://comptb.cects.com/2861-copying-directory-structures-without-files)

And for ant file creation, refer the following link, 
    [ant file](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html)